# Create writable directories

Tags: php, filesystems, chmod, mkdir

For a project I'm implementing a file-upload system. For every user account I would like the script to create a different sub-folder. Lets say their user_id's.

Each time a user is added, the system will create a new sub-folder for their own uploads. For example:

Uploads/
 - user1
 - user2
 - user3

By executing mkdir('Uploads/'.$user_id, 0777); it will create a new subfolder. Everything is fine.

However my application is not able to write to this folder. How do I have php make directories with the required file permissions? I have tried using chmod with no success.

Comment: On the server, set umask=022? even 000?

Comment: I hear `umask(0)` is used here, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What mode are the folders being created with? And is this 'application' of yours also running from the same webserver, or something external/non-php?

Comment: The application is running on the same webserver. I have tried umask(0) with no avail.

Answer (score 2):

This might help [chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) and [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

```
$dirMode = 0777;
mkdir($directory, $dirMode, true);

// chmod the directory since it doesn't seem to work on recursive paths
chmod($directory, $dirMode);
```

For mkdir, mode is ignored on Windows. and 0777 is by default. and the third param is recursive which allows the creation of nested directories specified in the pathname.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes the directory created with another mode than specified ( 0755 instead 0777  etc). 
to solve that use :

```
<?php 
$old = umask(0); 
mkdir($dir,0777); 
umask($old); 
?>
```